# Linear Alegbra - Matrices question true/false

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be any $n \times n$ matrix, defined over the real numbers, A is not invertible matrix.

Is $A+I$ invertible?

**My solution**

since $\det|A|=0$ and $\det|I|\neq0$ therefore $\det|A|+\det|I|\neq0$ hence $A+I$ invertible.

Comment: Why do you think that $|A+I| = |A| + |I|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $A$ be the matrix with $-1$ in the main diagonal except for the position $(1,1)$, clearly is non-invertible. What is $A+I$?

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is $n \times n$ and skew symmetric, that is $-A = A^{T}$, than $I_n + A$ is invertible. Here is why. Consider an arbitrary vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $x^{T}Ax$ is a scalar and is therefore equal to its transpose. So, $x^TAx = (x^TAx)^T = x^TA^Tx = - x^TAx \Rightarrow x^TAx = 0$. Now let $B = A + I_n$. Take $w$ to be some vector from the null space of $B$. Then \begin{align*} Bw = 0 \\ (A+I_n)w = 0 \\ w^T(A+I_n)w = 0 \\ w^TAw + w^TI_nw = 0 \\ w \cdot w = 0 \end{align*} Since $w = \begin{pmatrix} w_1 \\ w_2 \\ \vdots \\ w_n \end{pmatrix},$ $w \cdot w = w_1^2 + \dots + w_n^2 = 0,$ so $w$ is the zero vector. We see that the system $$(A+I_n)w = 0$$ only has the trivial solution and we conclude that $A+I_n$ is invertible when $A$ is skew symmetric.